# Vertical text in Tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to draw vertical text in Tkinter library? (Python recommended)

```
textID = w1.create_text(5, 5, anchor="nw")
w1.itemconfig(textID, text = "This is some text")
```

Answer (score 20):

Since people are being linked to this answer, I'll add an update.

[In tcl 8.6, the create_text method got an `angle` option](http://www.tcl.tk/cgi-bin/tct/tip/119). You can check your tcl version with `Tkinter.TclVersion`. If you have 8.6 or greater, you can use:

```
textID = w1.create_text(5, 5, anchor="nw", angle=90)
```

Comment: Angle to the rescue!  Why isn't this better documented??

Comment: FWIW, Python 2.7.16 still has tcl 8.5, but in Python 3.7.2, `tkinter.TclVersion` is indeed 8.6 (note all lowercase `tkinter`).

Answer (score 6):

If you are asking whether [`tkinter.Canvas.create_text`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_text-method) has something like this:

```
textID = w1.create_text(5, 5, anchor="nw", orient=tkinter.VERTICAL)
```

then the answer is no.  The `create_text` method can only create horizontal text.

---

However, you *can* use [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to create vertical text:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas()
canvas.grid()
canvas.create_text((10, 5), text="\n".join("This is some text"), anchor="nw")
root.mainloop()
```

Example:

[image]

While this may not be as elegant as simply setting an option on the `create_text` method, it does work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any way to make vertical text in tkinter, but you can just make an image of the vertical text you want

1. Screen shot the text you want and crop it
2. Screen shot the background colour and crop it
3. In word or powerpoint or something, put the text over the background
4. Take another screenshot and crop that
5. Put that screen shot in paint
6. Save the paint file in the same folder as your program
7. convert the paint file to a gif online: 
   http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-gif
8. Use the following code to put the image in your program

`vertical_text = PhotoImage(file = "<your file name>.gif")
 canvas.create_image(x, y, image = vertical_text)`

Here is a screenshot from a tkinter window in a program I'm making which lets you revise words
[image: example]

Comment: I hope this helps you! :) :)